# Violation of time reversal symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, perturbation-theory, symmetry-breaking, time-reversal-symmetry

Can anyone please provide me with an example of unperturbed Hamiltonian for a certain physical system, which has no time-reversal symmetry, the only condition is that the spectrum of unperturbed Hamiltonian must be well known? Also then please provide me with an example of perturbation for this specific case, for which the total perturbed Hamiltonian will also have no time-reversal symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of a simple harmonic oscillator with dissipation
$$H = e^{\gamma t}\left(-\frac1{2m}\partial_x^2 + \frac12 k x^2\right)\,.$$
Since $H$ is an odd function of $t$, it maximally breaks time reversal symmetry. Any perturbation to this Hamiltonian will also break time reversal symmetry. Here you need to be careful to pick the correct canonical momentum conjugate to $x$.

Comment: Although breaking time reversal, this Hamiltonian is not an odd function of $t$.